# symfony 1 Redirect only mobile devices to index page. But only once

Tags: javascript, php, symfony1

I'm using symfony 1
  when user comes to my page:

http://cinqmondes-marseille.com

with mobile device
I'm forcing a redirection to mobile page:

http://cinqmondes-marseille.com/smartphone/index.php

with a simple script:

```
<?php 
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
$mobileRedirectOnce = $sf_user->getAttribute('mobileRedirectOnce');
if ($detect->isMobile() && $mobileRedirectOnce == null) {
    $sf_user->setAttribute('mobileRedirectOnce', 1);
    echo "window.location = 'http://cinqmondes-marseille.com/smartphone/index.php';";
}
?>

if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ||
navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Palm/i) )
{
    window.location = 'http://cinqmondes-marseille.com/smartphone/index.php';
}

    </script>
```

and when he click to:

VOIR NOTRE SITE

I would like to redirect him to a desktop version page

http:/ /cinqmondes-marseille.com/

not again to the mobile page

but my script is redirecting again to mobile page

because it detect a mobile device

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's your javascript condition, it doesn't do any other check than check for mobile device. You already check for mobile device in php, so remove it, it's not necessary.